# Trying to prove the equivalence of two notions of a tangent space of a scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes

I am going the proof of: Let $X$ be a scheme of finite type over $k$, $x \in X$ is a closed point.
The following two $k$-vector spaces are canonically isomorphic.

1. $T_x = \hom_{k}(\mathfrak{m}_x/\mathfrak{m}_x^2, k)$
2. The space of derivations $D: O_{X,x} \to k$ over $k$.

The direction 1) to 2) of the proof I can follow.
For the other direction he defines a map from 2) to 1) as follows.
Given $\ell: \mathfrak{m}_x/ \mathfrak{m}_x^2 \to k$, define $D$ by
$$
D(f) := \ell[f - f(x)]
$$
and this is supposed to be a derivation. I am not seeing how this $D$ is well defined... Can someone clarify this please? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\require{AMScd}$
To check that $D$ is well-defined, the only thing you really need to check is that $f - f(x)\in\mathfrak{m}_x.$ Indeed, $D$ is defined by taking the *class* of $f - f(x)$ in $\mathfrak{m}_x/\mathfrak{m}_x^2$ and applying $\ell$ to it. Observe that there's no choice involved here! You're not using the representative $f - f(x)$ to define the map, you're using the class of $f - f(x)$ itself.

Issues of being well-defined usually arise in situations like the following. Suppose you have a quotient map of rings $\pi : R\to R/I,$ and suppose you have a ring map $f : R\to S.$ You can try to define a map $\overline{f} : R/I\to S$ by the formula $\overline{f}(r + I) := f(r),$ but this in general will depend on the choice of representative $r$ of the coset $r + I.$ So, in a situation like this, you need to check that $f(r) = f(r')$ for any two $r,r'\in R$ such that $r - r'\in I.$ This amounts to showing that the map $f$ sends every element of $I$ to $0.$ (In fact, this is the universal property of the quotient $R/I$: any map $f : R\to S$ such that $f$ maps every element of $I$ to $0$ descends uniquely to a map $\overline{f} : R/I\to S$ making the diagram
$$\begin{CD}
R @>\pi>> R/I\\
@VfVV @VV\overline{f}V\\
S @>\operatorname{id}>> S
\end{CD}$$
commute.

However, if on the other hand you have a quotient map of rings $\pi : R\to R/I$ and you have a map $f : R/I\to S,$ there's a natural way to get a map $R\to S$ -- simply compose the two! You can always form the composition
$$
R\xrightarrow{\pi} R/I\xrightarrow{f} S
$$
without worrying about issues of being well-defined, since composition of ring maps is always well-defined.

In your situation, you have a map $\ell : \mathfrak{m}_x/\mathfrak{m}_x^2\to k$ from the quotient, and you're making a new map by starting with an element of $\mathfrak{m}_x,$ looking at its image under the canonical map $\mathfrak{m}_x\to\mathfrak{m}_x/\mathfrak{m}_x^2$, and then applying $\ell.$ This is perfectly legal!

So, to see that $f - f(x)\in\mathfrak{m}_x,$ observe first that because $X$ is a $k$-scheme and $x$ is a closed point, you have a canonical map $\pi : \mathcal{O}_{X,x}\to\mathcal{O}_{X,x}/\mathfrak{m_x}\cong k.$ Moreover, this map comes with a canonical section $\sigma : k\to\mathcal{O}_{X,x};$ that is, we have $\pi\circ\sigma = \operatorname{id}_k.$

The second thing we need to note is that $f(x)$ is simply the image of $f$ under the composition $$\mathcal{O}_{X,x}\xrightarrow{\pi}k\xrightarrow{\sigma}\mathcal{O}_{X,x}.$$

Now, we proceed to make sense of the construction. We can compute
\begin{align*}
\pi(f - f(x)) &= \pi(f - \sigma\circ\pi(f))\\
&= \pi(f) - \pi\circ\sigma\circ\pi(f)\\
&= \pi(f) - \operatorname{id}\circ\pi(f)\\
&= \pi(f) - \pi(f)\\
&=0.
\end{align*}
Thus, $f - f(x)$ does in fact lie in $\mathfrak{m}_x = \ker(\pi).$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought $f(x)$ was an element in $O_{X,x}/\mathfrak{m}_x$, so in order to compute $f - f(x)$, don't I have to choose a  representative $f(x) = g + \mathfrak{m}_x$, say, and then $f - f(x)$ 'is' $f - g$? or am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: @JohnnyT. Ah, I see your confusion! Well, $f(x)$ is an element of $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}/\mathfrak{m}_x\cong k,$ but there's a canonical choice of representative, given via the section $\sigma : k\to\mathcal{O}_{X,x}.$ This is the one we want, because we want to think of $f(x)$ as the [constant] value of $f$ evaluated at $x.$ Indeed, if you wanted to show that this was independent of choice of preimage of $f(x),$ you'd be in trouble: note that $f$ itself is a possible preimage, but if we chose $f(x)$ to be $f,$ then we'd have $D(f) = 0$ for all $f,$ and certainly we want nonzero derivations.

Comment: Suppose for example that $\mathcal{O}_{X,x} = k[\![t]\!]$, that the map $k[\![t]\!]\to k$ evaluates a power series at $t = 0,$ and that the section $k\to k[\![t]\!]$ is the canonical embedding of elements of $k$ as constant power series. We have $\mathfrak{m}_x = (t),$ and $(t)/(t^2) = kt,$ so let's take $\ell : kt\to k$ to simply be the map given by $t\mapsto 1.$ If we let $f = t + 1,$ then we have $\ell(f - f(x)) = \ell(t + 1 - 1) = \ell(t) = 1,$ but $\ell((t + 1) - (t + 1)) = \ell(0) = 0,$ which shows that this construction is *not* independent of the choice of preimage of $f.$

Comment: makes a lot more sense now. thank you!

Comment: By the way are you assuming $k$ to be algebraically closed, or is this not necessary? (for getting the isomorphism $O_{X,x}/m_x$)

Comment: It's not necessary to assume that $k$ is algebraically closed, only that $X$ is a $k$-scheme and that $x$ is a $k$-point. This gives you field maps $k\to \mathcal{O}_{X,x}/\mathfrak{m}_x\to k,$ and from the $k$-scheme structure of everything you know that the composition $k\to k$ is the identity. Thus, $1 = [k : k] = [k : \mathcal{O}_{X,x}/\mathfrak{m}_x][\mathcal{O}_{X,x}/\mathfrak{m}_x : k],$ so that $[\mathcal{O}_{X,x}/\mathfrak{m}_x:k] = 1$, and hence $k\to \mathcal{O}_{X,x}/\mathfrak{m}_x$ and $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}/\mathfrak{m}_x\to k$ are isomorphisms.

Comment: In fact, you don't even need the fact that $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}/\mathfrak{m}_x\cong k,$ only that you have a map $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}\to k$ and a section of this map.